# read a users UID from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read in uid into a var but for some reason it does not work.  My database is:

[image: firebase structure]

```
if (user) { // User is signed in!
    var uid = user.uid;
    var refreshToken = user.refreshToken;            
    firebase.database().ref().child("owners").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).on('value', function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var controller=childSnapshot.val().name;
        console.log('controller is: ' + controller);
    });
});
```

my console.log statement never shows to the console. Any help would be appreciated as the really has me stumped right now.

Comment: Can you place a `console.log` before `snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)`  to see if the code is getting to your inner function?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("owners").child("Pellet_Pirate_1").child("details").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).on('value', function (snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var controller=childSnapshot.val().name;
                console.log('controller is: ' + Controller);
                });
            });
```